# How to define that android app is in background?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a broadcast receiver, which launches a service, and in this service I should check, if my main application is active, or in background. Are there any methods how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Application class and store the current state of your application. You will need to update it from every Activity's onPause() and onResume() methods.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static boolean isAppVisible() {
      return visible;
   }  

    public static void inForeground() {
      visible = true;
    }

    public static void inBackground() {
      visible = false;
    }

    private static boolean visible;
}
```

Register your application class in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="your.app.package.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Add onPause and onResume to every Activity in the project (you may create a common superclass for your Activities if you'd like to, but if your activity is already extended from MapActivity/ListActivity etc. you still need to write the following by hand):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.inBackground();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MyApplication.inForeground();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Context ctx = context.getApplicationContext();

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

// get the info from the currently running task
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
boolean flag = false;
try {
    /**
     * take fore ground activity name
     */
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    if (printLog) {
        Log.d("Tag", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
        Log.d("Tag", "Number Of Activities : "
                + taskInfo.get(0).numRunning);
        Log.d("Tag",
                "Componenet Info : " + componentInfo.getPackageName());
        Log.d("Tag",
                "Componenet Info : " + componentInfo.getClassName());
    }
    /**
     * All activities name of a package to compare with fore ground
     * activity. if match found, no notification displayed.
     */
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(
            "com.package_name",
            PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    ActivityInfo[] list = info.activities;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        Log.d("Tag","Activity : "+list[i].name);

        if (list[i].name.equals(componentInfo.getClassName())) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if(flag)
    {
        //activity is running
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And take `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />` permission in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Considering implementing an application that keep track if the app goes front or back using onPause() and onResume().
Have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862048/1503155).
Hope it helps.